# how to continue the session from the client side using FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, session

I'm using FLEX for front side of my web application. My task now is to handle session timeout. I can capture session timeout now. What I want to do is let the user continue the session, meaning that let the user stay on the current page (for example, current menu selection or current table selected) and restore every content that users have put in the text field.

For example, there are four division in my menu: Front page,management,events and setting. When the user click "management", there would be some text fields like user name, address or other info. When the session is expired, the user can continue the session, staying on "management" state and regain what they have typed in the text fields. How to do that? Thank you for your reviewing!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a in Flex component that periodically calls the back-end to keep the session opened.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to display the login panel or whatever in front of the current "management" panel.

As soon as the user re logged in, just switch back to the previous configuration by hiding the the login panel and the user will be able to continue working without loosing anything.

HIH
M.

Comment: r u sure the contents are all still there? Maybe a global variable would help to store the contents. But how to stay on the current page? Actually, besides the Header Menu, there is a side menu on the left, So I need to capture both the selections of the Header Menu and Side Menu

Comment: Flex in more or less like a flat client. If you put a panel in front of all the other, what is behind remain exactly intact. When you will add a panel in front, the client browser won't actually reload an html page. Just swipe off the panel and everything will be back.

Comment: So according to what you say, when I capture the session expiration, I would show a alert() message with an OK button, click "OK" would just simply close the message box. But to actually continue the session, I should still need to login to establish communication between client and server, right?